# How to bring a list from a text file into python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists in a text file, when I read it into python, how do I assign it to a variable as a list rather then a string?

writing to text file:

```
file1 = open("contacts.txt", "w")
file1.write(str(contact_list))
```

inside of the text file:

```
[['Name', 'Email', 'Phone Number'], ['Name1', 'Email1', 'Phone Number1']]
```

```
file1 = open("contacts.txt", "r")
contact_list = file1.readline().rstrip()
print(contact_list[0])
```

Treated like a string ^

When I try to print index 0 from the list it treats it like a string

Comment: It appears that you own the code that writes to the text file, in which case you should consider using a more exchangeable format such as JSON or YAML, or if your script is the only consumer of the file, consider a more space and time-efficient format such as `pickle`.

Answer (score 0):

You saved a string representation of the list. If the values of the list are all python literals (string, int, float, etc...), then you can have python parse them again

```
import ast
with open("contacts.txt") as file1:
    contact_list = ast.literal_eval(file1.read())
print(contact_list[0])
```

Alternately, you could save in another format such as JSON or even a python [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) file.